# button redirecting to wrong path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using a link button in my blade view. The code is as follows:

```
<a href="conclusion" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>End Case</a>
```

The url of the page on which this link button is:

```
http://localhost/cases/137/responses/30
```

The result of my button should be

```
http://localhost/cases/137/responses/30/conclusion
```

but it is redirecting to

```
http://localhost/cases/137/responses/conclusion
```

My laravel route definition is:

```
get('/cases/{id}/responses/{respId}/conclusion', 'HomeController@conclusion');
```

What is wrong with it? How can I do it?

Comment: Where is the laravel route definition for your conclusion page? You tag it with laravel but you provide no code related to it.

Comment: Are you talking about `get ('/cases/{id}/responses/{respId}/conclusion', 'HomeController@conclusion');` in route.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save way to generate URLs is to always use Laravels helper functions. This way you don't have any problem with relative URLs as it always generates a full URL. In your case `action()` would be appropriate:

```
<a href="{{ action('HomeController@conclusion', [$id, $respId]) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>End Case</a>
```

Alternatively you can give your route a name:

```
get('/cases/{id}/responses/{respId}/conclusion', [
    'as' => 'conclusion',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@conclusion'
]);
```

And then:

```
<a href="{{ route('conclusion', [$id, $respId]) }}" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>End Case</a>
```

Comment: I love this solution. But the resulting url is 
`http://localhost/cases/%7Bid%7D/responses/%7BrespId%7D/conclusion` 
I want the values of $id and $respId in this url

Comment: Ah of course. Well you can either pass them from the controller to the view or use `Route::input('id')` directly in the view. (I'd prefer the first way)

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting is not relative to the current path.  Its relative to the index.xxx.  I suggest that you use a fully qualified path.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the current url is pointing to a document, not a folder: https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/

When using relative href's you actually point to a document in the current folder. While your current url has no ending slash (`/`) it's interpreted as a document and the relative url will actually replace the document name.

So at this time you are pointing to the document `conclusion` in the folder `http://localhost/cases/137/responses/`, because `30` is also "just" a document in that folder.

In order to fix your problem you should hit your page as a folder `http://localhost/cases/137/responses/30/` which allows for relative url's `href="conclusion"` to point to `http://localhost/cases/137/responses/30/conclusion`

To ensure this works in laravel, your route that points to the response should have an ending `/`. An even better solution would be to generate the route to the pages using the laravel helper functions like `route()` and `action()`; see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls